# HTML5 Canvas different color values on different machines

Tags: javascript, html, macos, canvas

We're building a game where we use texture masks to denote certain properties on objects. For example, a blue pixel with the value 250 (x, x, 250) on the textureA mask denotes that this is the place where textureB gets attached to it, etc. All good.

Until we tested it on Mac (using Linux/Ubuntu normally), and figured out that the colors were different. At first we thought it caused by some of the components/plugins/software we're using, but by disabling them one by one, we got the bare HTML canvas and an image. Unfortunately, this gave us different results as well.

So, this is the testing code we run from the console (please ignore the missing semi-colons, scope issues,etc... this is just something we used for quick testing):

```
// create an image in the DOM
img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '/assets/characters/maleWhite/torso.png';

// create canvas and the context
canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
canvas.width = img.width; 
canvas.height = img.height; 

// draw the image onto the canvas
ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height );

// get pixel data
sourceData = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, img.width, img.height );
maskData = sourceData.data;

// output the RGB data for those pixel that have blue value bigger than 0
// (pixels that have even the slightest tint of blue)
for (i = 0; i < maskData.length; i += 4) {
    if (maskData[i+2] > 0) console.log('rgb', maskData[i], maskData[i+1], maskData[i+2], '------------');
}
```

And the results we got on Linux/Ubuntu machines are the same (pasted from the console, the numbers in separate lines denoting how many repeating log lines are there, and the numbers between `rgb` and `----` are the RGB values of each bluish pixel):

```
rgb 255 0 243 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 91 3 242 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 0 3 242 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 68 3 242 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 0 3 242 ------------ VM124:11
9
rgb 0 0 253 ------------ VM124:11
2
rgb 0 0 255 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 211 0 255 ------------ VM124:11
2
rgb 0 0 255 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 177 0 255 ------------ VM124:11
2
rgb 0 0 255 ------------ VM124:11
rgb 38 0 255 ------------ VM124:11
6
rgb 0 0 252 ------------ VM124:11
3
rgb 4 0 241 ------------ VM124:11
3
rgb 0 0 252 ------------ VM124:11
6
rgb 4 0 241 ------------ VM124:11
9
rgb 0 0 247 ------------ VM124:11
9
rgb 4 0 246 ------------ VM124:11
9
rgb 4 0 249 ------------ VM124:11
9
rgb 255 0 248 ------------
```

However, on one Mac we get the following:

```
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
2
rgb 255 0 238 ------------ VM67:11
85
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
2
rgb 255 0 238 ------------ VM67:11
1129
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 253 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
85
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 225 0 19 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 240 0 21 ------------ VM67:11
85
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 212 0 17 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 242 0 21 ------------ VM67:11
85
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 200 0 15 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 196 0 15 ------------ VM67:11
3
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 228 0 19 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 176 0 12 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 111 0 4 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 64 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 51 0 1 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 111 0 4 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 161 0 10 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 234 0 20 ------------ VM67:11
68
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 184 0 13 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 145 0 8 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 166 0 11 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 67 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 91 0 3 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 220 0 18 ------------ VM67:11
66
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 176 0 12 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 83 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 49 0 1 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 155 0 9 ------------ VM67:11
65
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 135 0 7 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 151 0 8 ------------ VM67:11
64
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 111 0 4 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 160 0 10 ------------ VM67:11
63
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 94 0 236 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 0 0 236 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 228 0 19 ------------ VM67:11
61
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 248 0 22 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 70 0 236 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 0 0 236 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 71 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
61
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 231 0 19 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 44 0 1 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 166 0 11 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 252 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
59
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 201 0 15 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 155 0 9 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
59
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 173 0 12 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 170 0 11 ------------ VM67:11
60
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 135 0 7 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 185 0 13 ------------ VM67:11
60
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 84 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 162 0 10 ------------ VM67:11
59
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 236 0 20 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 101 0 4 ------------ VM67:11
59
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 133 0 6 ------------ VM67:11
58
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 211 0 17 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 163 0 10 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
2
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
53
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 68 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 181 0 13 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 252 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
52
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 118 0 5 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 180 0 13 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 254 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
2
rgb 253 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
48
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 241 0 21 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 110 0 4 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 77 0 2 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 209 0 16 ------------ VM67:11
3
rgb 255 0 23 ------------ VM67:11
45
rgb 255 0 24 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 223 0 19 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 146 0 8 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 47 0 1 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 108 0 4 ------------ VM67:11
rgb 190 0 14 ----------
```

And, on another Mac, even more different values:

```
32
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
2
rgb 252 38 240 ------------ VM728:3
85
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
2
rgb 252 38 240 ------------ VM728:3
1129
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 239 12 25 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 242 12 26 ------------ VM728:3
85
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 213 9 21 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 227 10 23 ------------ VM728:3
85
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 201 8 19 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 229 11 24 ------------ VM728:3
7
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
6
rgb 250 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
72
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 189 7 18 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 186 7 17 ------------ VM728:3
3
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 216 9 22 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 166 5 14 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 105 2 5 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 60 1 2 ------------ VM728:3
6
rgb 37 0 1 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 47 0 1 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 105 2 5 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 152 4 12 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 221 10 23 ------------ VM728:3
68
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 174 6 15 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 137 4 10 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 246 12 26 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 157 4 13 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 63 1 2 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 86 1 4 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 209 9 20 ------------ VM728:3
66
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 166 5 14 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 78 1 3 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 45 0 1 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 146 4 11 ------------ VM728:3
65
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 127 3 8 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 142 4 10 ------------ VM728:3
64
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 105 2 5 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 151 4 12 ------------ VM728:3
62
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 250 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 91 35 238 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 10 34 238 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 216 9 22 ------------ VM728:3
61
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 235 11 25 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 69 35 238 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 10 34 238 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 67 1 2 ------------ VM728:3
2
rgb 250 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
59
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 218 10 22 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 41 0 1 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 157 4 13 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 238 12 25 ------------ VM728:3
59
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 190 7 18 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 146 4 11 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 245 12 26 ------------ VM728:3
59
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 164 5 14 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 161 5 13 ------------ VM728:3
60
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 127 3 8 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 175 6 15 ------------ VM728:3
60
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 79 1 3 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 153 4 12 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 251 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
58
rgb 252 13 27 ------------ VM728:3
rgb 223 10 23 ------------
```

As you see, there are many more bluish pixels rendered on Macs. And all the pixels have modifications of the green values too.

Here is the same pixel represented on two machines: `0, 0, 252` becomes `10, 35, 248` on a Mac.

All machines are primarily using Chrome. Each machine get the same results in Firefox, though.

**What is the way to overcome this? Why is this happening?**

We can, of course, write a code to map each color value to the "right" value, but that solution is just stupid and we'd rather not take that path.

Comment: Though i have no idea how to get around the issue, this seems to be caused by OSX's way of handling color spaces and display color profiles.
See : http://iccir.com/articles/osx-color-conversions/

Comment: Thanks. :)
I'm sticking around to see if anyone knows a solution for this.

Comment: As am I, but I am working on this project with @Shomz.

Comment: Interesting, so the HEX representations probably have the same effect? EDIT: Apparently, it doesn't look good. It's a known issue and hasn't been resolved yet.

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/google-chrome-for-mac-css-colors-and-display-profiles

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872

Comment: @Sri-- Yes, the original color values are off, and no matter where you use them, they will stay off. We won't mind if it alters the look of the image, but we're using color codes to represent different data so we're basically getting wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is sort of pointed out in the comments. The issue is related to how the browser handles ICC color profiles. The browsers try to correct the images but it does not always work as intended as here.

There is no programmatic work around for this. You can do test in your local environment by turning off the color management options in the browser, but this will only affect your browser, not the user's.

You can try strip off any ICC profile the image has (in Photoshop use Save for web) or you can do a simple "color correction" if the palette is limited by iterating the pixels finding a palette entry and use a tolerance value to kick the value back to the intended value.

This is of course not so elegant - the option is to move the tolerance check to the main chain if possible (ie. gradients or close colors won't work well with this).

My 2 cents...

Comment: Thank you. For some reason we thought the color profiling kicks in at a much later stage - sometime before rendering the image onto the screen. Guess not. Seems like we'll have to reexport the artwork with no ICC profile data. I'll accept this answer if nobody comes up with a more concrete solution.

Comment: @Shomz the correction happens at load time. I forgot to mention also gamma correction that can *may* take place with or without ICC (saving gamma information in PNG is optional format-wise).